# Interchangeability of 'vendor' and 'service provider'

Tags: meaning, difference, synonyms

My use case is variable and database table/column naming. The table will reference professional photography service providers. While appropriate unabbreviated naming is a must, a shorter name would be preferable.

My intuition suggests that a vendor is rather selling products than rendering services, but I am completely unsure about how real and how essential this difference is.

Is it appropriate to replace 'service provider' with 'vendor' for reasons of brevity in this and other cases?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English business lingo, *vendor* can range from a hot dog vendor to a Hewlett Packard or a Microsoft. A vendor can sell products and/or provide services. VENDORS would be a perfectly acceptable choice for a database table name in the US, both in the back-end and in the UI. COMPANIES would also work, as would PROVIDERS.  If you need a table for companies that sell photographic equipment and related components, they would be called SUPPLIERS.

Comment: Many thanks, TRomano. I am accepting your answer, because it is more consistent with my intuition :) Funny how language intuitions can vary between countries.

Answer (score 1):

Vendor is more like a hot dog vendor. Someone who sells goods.

Service provider is more like telephone/internet/cable provider. A company that provides the cables and wires and technology to make those services available to you.

I don't think *photography service providers* is the correct term. Yes, they provide a service of going out and taking photos for you, but you also get a product back, being the pictures.

I'd think something like *Photographers* would be a better table name. And then have a column which would indicate if they are freelance or a company.

Comment: Thank you, cVplZ. I have accepted a different answer, simply for emotional reasons. There seem to be a difference in the perceived meaning of the word 'vendor'. Were you referring to American English as well, or a different variety?